# Force all X's to be 0

Tags: verilog

I have a 6 bit input value, that throughout my logic I want to make sure there are no X's (which are uninitialized values(?)). Is there anyway I can force it to make sure any X's in it are 0's and not X's. Would I AND it with something?

```
module m(
   input [5:0] switches,
);

endmodule;
```

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 0):

You can mask it with a different *initialized* signal.
E.g. assuming you know the condition `init_condition` after which, there are no longer X's in your input:

```
logic init_mask;
always_ff @(posedge clk, negedge rstn)
    if (!rstn) init_mask <= 1'b0;
    else if (init_condition) init_mask <= 1'b1;

assign outp = {6{init_mask}} & switches;
```

When reset is low, `init_mask` FF is set to `0`, masking the output to zeros as well. When the `init_condition` is captured high at the posedge of the clock, `init_mask` FF is set to `1` and your `switches` input will make it through the output unmasked.

Answer (score 0):

Generally in hardware, dual flop synchronizers can be used to remove `X` values. However that will work only, if you have `X` for certain period of time.

If you have constant `X` then I think there can be no digital hardware to convert it to valid `0` or `1`.

Here is the code for dual flop synchronizer.

```
module temp();
  wire a, b;
  reg x, y;
  reg clk;

  assign b = y;
//  buf (strong1, strong0) (b, a);

  assign a = 1'bx;
  always #5 clk = ~clk;

  initial
  begin
    $monitor("b - %b", b);
    clk = 0;
    #40; 
  end

  always @(posedge clk)
  begin
    x <= a;
    y <= x;
  end
endmodule
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't synthesizable, but if you're trying to mask `X` in your testbench, you can use the [`case equality`](http://www.asic-world.com/verilog/operators1.html) operator `===` to check for `X` or `Z`.

```
wire your_bit_with_xs_forced_to_0 = (your_bit === 1'dx) ? 1'b0 : your_bit;
```